# Option to display diffs of the Markdown source, not the rendered text

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, diff

Consider the following example:

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3544794/revisions

It is very hard to tell what Quintin changed here. He actually added a link. It would be nice if it were possible to switch to a mode in which a diff of the Markdown source is shown.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [Diff is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75377)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say we could go even a step further and only display the diff in markdown.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the fact that the improved diff engine now shows the change correctly in the standard view, the revision list now also offers both a side-by-side HTML diff and a diff of the Markdown source, so this is doubly [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Answer (score 0):

Why not display a green +, a red - or a blue x on the left of the rendering to indicate this line has been added, deleted or modified, respectively? And on hovering the blue x, the change's source is shown.